# dplyr: deselecting columns given by

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I deselect columns given in the `...` argument of a self written function. (I also need to select the columns at another point, so just specifying the columns with `-` in `...` does not solve my problem.)

Any soltions are apreciated, `select`-helpers, manipulating `quosures` or expressions, ...

```
# very simple example data
test <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, c=1:3)

# function skeleton
testfun <- function(x, ...){
  y <- select(x, ...)
  z <- select(x, -...) # does of course not work like this
  return(list(y, z))   # just as an example
}

# calling the function to select different columns
testfun(test, a)
testfun(test, a, b)
```

Comment: I would use `select_` and pass in a character (vector).

Comment: Lionel Henry uses this example in his webinar https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/?wvideo=zt9kl921rh and solve it with `neg_dots <- map(dots, ~ quo(- !!.x))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These easiest solution would be to select the positive columns, and then compare names to figure out which columns to drop, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828591/1084259).

To work on the dots directly,

1. We will capture them in a list of quosures (`quos`).
2. Unquote and splice the dots in with `UQS` for the positive selection.
3. Do the same thing inside of `c()` so that we have a vector of selection.
4. Negate that vector to do the negative selection.

This is the transformation described by (3) and (4).

```
library(dplyr)
dots <- quos(a, b)
quos(-c(UQS(dots)))
#> [[1]]
#> <quosure: frame>
#> ~-c(~a, ~b)
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "quosures"
```

The full solution then would be

```
test <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3)

# function skeleton
testfun <- function(x, ...) {
  dots <- quos(...)
  y <- select(x, UQS(dots))
  z <- select(x, -c(UQS(dots)))
  return(list(y, z))   
}

testfun(test, a)
#> [[1]]
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   b c
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3

testfun(test, a, b)
#> [[1]]
#>   a b
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   c
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
```

Test on selection helpers.

```
testfun(test, starts_with("b"), one_of("c"))
#> [[1]]
#>   b c
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
```

Comment: it seems `c` is not necessary, and the line for `y` was already working in OP's question, so you could just change the line for `z` into `z <- select(x, -!!!quos(...))`

Comment: my bad, you need `c` or `testfun(test, a,b)` will fail, the line then becomes `z <- select(x, -c(!!!quos(...)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick with `purrr::modify_at`

```
library(purrr)
testfun <- function(x, ...){
  y <- select(x, ...)
  z <- modify_at(x,c(...),~NULL)
  return(list(y, z))   # just as an example
}

testfun(test,"a")
# [[1]]
#   a
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3
# 
# [[2]]
#   b c
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
```

Comment: This looks really nice, I'll try this, accepted the other answer, because it was closer to what I had in mind when I asked the question, but this looks more practical.

Answer (score 1):

What about that one?

```
testfun <- function(x, ...){
  y <- select(x, ...)
  z <- x[, !names(x) %in% names(y)]
  return(list(y, z))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
testfun <- function(x, y, z){
  y1 <- select(x, y)
  z1 <- select(x, -one_of(z)) 
  return(list(y1, z1)) 
}
testfun(test, "a", "b")
[[1]]
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3

[[2]]
  a c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

You can also specify more variables using `c`

```
testfun(test, c("a", "c"), c("b", "a"))
```