# Select all but some columns in dplyr with unquoting

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, nse, tidyeval

I want to use `select(data, -var)` but keep `var` flexible. This works if `var` is of length one using `select(data, -!!var)` (with `var <- quo(var)`) , but it does not if it is of length > 1. Any ideas why?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.1
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

q <- quo(cyl)

mtcars %>%
  select(-!!q)
#>                      mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant             18.1 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Duster 360          14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Merc 240D           24.4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230            22.8 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 280            19.2 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C           17.8 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Fiat 128            32.4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora       15.0 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Volvo 142E          21.4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

q2 <- quos(cyl, wt)
mtcars %>%
  select(!!!q2)
#>                     cyl    wt
#> Mazda RX4             6 2.620
#> Mazda RX4 Wag         6 2.875
#> Datsun 710            4 2.320
#> Hornet 4 Drive        6 3.215
#> Hornet Sportabout     8 3.440
#> Valiant               6 3.460
#> Duster 360            8 3.570
#> Merc 240D             4 3.190
#> Merc 230              4 3.150
#> Merc 280              6 3.440
#> Merc 280C             6 3.440
#> Merc 450SE            8 4.070
#> Merc 450SL            8 3.730
#> Merc 450SLC           8 3.780
#> Cadillac Fleetwood    8 5.250
#> Lincoln Continental   8 5.424
#> Chrysler Imperial     8 5.345
#> Fiat 128              4 2.200
#> Honda Civic           4 1.615
#> Toyota Corolla        4 1.835
#> Toyota Corona         4 2.465
#> Dodge Challenger      8 3.520
#> AMC Javelin           8 3.435
#> Camaro Z28            8 3.840
#> Pontiac Firebird      8 3.845
#> Fiat X1-9             4 1.935
#> Porsche 914-2         4 2.140
#> Lotus Europa          4 1.513
#> Ford Pantera L        8 3.170
#> Ferrari Dino          6 2.770
#> Maserati Bora         8 3.570
#> Volvo 142E            4 2.780

mtcars %>%
  select(-!!!q2)
#> Error: Can't use `!!!` at top level
```

Created on 2018-08-10 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001012/excluding-multiple-columns-based-on-unquote-splicing?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-c(!!!q2)`. Just like you would when using `select` where you do not need two vars, like `select(-c(cyl, wt))`

```
mtcars %>%
  select(-c(!!!q2))
                     mpg  disp  hp drat  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0 160.0 110 3.90 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0 110 3.90 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8 108.0  93 3.85 18.61  1  1    4    1
```